# Developing a lab to identify the concentration of casein in organic milk

Tags: experimental-chemistry, proteins

I am currently attempting to create a feasible lab design that will enable me to identify the concentration of casein protein in organic milk without having to use spectroscopy. Thus far I have thought of separating the casein from the milk by exploiting its pH of isoelectric point of 4.6 to form curdles and filter the curdles out using a filter. Furthermore, I would rinse and leave the curdles to dry till I am left with casein powder. Following this I would compare the weight of the casein powder to the weight of the original sample of milk I extract it from. Is this a feasible method or are the any other alternative ways also not using any major equipment?

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable. You can search for "casein isolation method".  I found this for instance: facstaff.bloomu.edu/mpugh/Experiment%2011.pdf

Comment: @NightWriter The link you posted has been very helpful so far, thank you.

Comment: This [book](https://books.google.cl/books/about/Laboratory_Experiments_for_Introduction.html?id=m-cgwEAgJCMC&redir_esc=y) describes in great detail an experimental procedure for what are you looking for.

Comment: And what's an organic milk? Milk with alcohol instead of (quite inorganic) water? BTW you just described a method of making cottage cheese, not isolating casein (more useful and tasty though).

Comment: @Mithoron I can't tell if your response is tongue-in-cheek or not, but https://www.ams.usda.gov/grades-standards/organic-standards.